# How to add buttons in xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, xaml-designer

I'm working on a project in XAML, and I want to add two buttons that contain the image of the add and delete.
attached screenshot of the buttons I want to add.

[image]

Comment: Did you mean to tag this C?

Comment: I want to tag C #, error of me part.

Comment: If you use png or bmp these are bitmap and will not be as crisp as a vector based approach. You also cannot easily re-use pieces like that label if you use images. The way I would do this would be to use a drawingvisual and geometries within that. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/using-drawingvisual-objects https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.drawingcontext.drawgeometry?view=netframework-4.7.2 You can obtain geometries off the web, convert from svg or trace from bitmap using inkscape or grab from syncfusion metro studio.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you do not have a small example of code to provide me?

Answer (score 0):

Sample of `Button` with `Image` inside.

Because `Button` itself do not have `Image` property, you should make image as `Content` of `Button` element.

```
        <Button x:Name="btnNewItem" Command="{Binding Path=NewItemCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Value="/Resources/Bitmaps/Add.png"/>
                <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="Button text" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
```